# uwp TextBlock height problem in a single line

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, textblock

I have a sort of chat like feature in a uwp app, some chat messages can have long texts, hence they will be multiline, and some will have small texts hence single line.

The issue I am having is that textblock with **single line** has **extra space left on bottom of it**, probably because of textblock extra unnecessary height, meanwhile multiline textblock has same margin left above and below it (as you can see in the image below). I want uniform margins for single line textblocks as well.

[image: chat msgs]

In below image look closely the bottom side of multiline text has less space and bottom side of single line text has more space.

[image: different margins appearing]

I tried to fix it by setting **VerticalContentAlignment** of the **ListViewItems** to **Top** that solved this issue but created a vertical margin issue as you can see in the image below vertical margins between items is inconsistent :

[image: vertical margin issue]

Below is the relevant code.

**MainPage**

```
<Page
x:Class="ChatMarginBug.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:ChatMarginBug"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ChatListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,2,12,2" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyTweets}" Style="{StaticResource ChatListViewStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TweetData">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{x:Bind MyTweetType, Converter={StaticResource TweetTypeToHAConverter1}}" x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Bind MyTweetType, Converter={StaticResource TweetTypeToC1DefConverter1}}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Bind MyTweetType, Converter={StaticResource TweetTypeToC2DefConverter1}}" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="{x:Bind MyTweetType, Converter={StaticResource TweetTypeToMetaDataColumnConverter1}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="0,0,0,4"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource TinyFontSize}"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                            Text="Name" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource TinyFontSize}"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                            Text="15:00" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid
                        Grid.Column="{x:Bind MyTweetType, Converter={StaticResource TweetTypeToMsgColumnConverter1}}"
                        MinWidth="120"
                        Background="{x:Bind MyTweetType, Converter={StaticResource TweetTypeToColorConverter1}}">
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="16,8,16,8"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource SmallFontSize}"
                            FontWeight="Normal"
                            Text="{x:Bind Text}"
                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                            TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyTweets = new List<TweetData>
        {
            new TweetData{ Text="abqrwfsddggc", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abqrwfsddggasasasc", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abqrwfsddassqsasacbvretgergggc", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcalkdjdjjd qdjqwpodwqpodqwjdqwkj qdkjqwkdjqwlkdjqlkdjaslkj   qieoqieowqdjwkjwkj kdwqjqwlk;lqwkd;lkd;laskd;laks;dlkaskld;lakdpoiwdpowqkd;l qwioeqwijdkqwjdlkndlksanlcsmcsa qwkkjeqwjdlkqwjdlksadmasldjl;qkd;asljdlqwkhdlwqk", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcalkdjkjwkj kdwqjqwlk;lqwkd;lkd;laskd;laks;dlkaskld;lakdpoiwdpowqkd;l qwioeqwijdkqwjdlkndlksanlcsmcsa qwkkjeqwjdlkqwjdlksadmasldjl;qkd;asljdlqwkhdlwqk", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abewqeqweqweqwe", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcalkdjdjjd qdjqwpodwqpodqwjdqwkj qdkjqwkdjqwlkdjqlkdjaslkj   qieoqieowqdjwkjwkj kdwqjqwlk;lqwkd;lkd;laskd;laks;dlkaskld;lakdpoiwdpowqkd;l qwioeqwijdkqwjdlkndlksanlcsmcsa qwkkjeqwjdlkqwjdlksadmasldjl;qkd;asljdlqwkhdlwqk", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcalkdjdjjd qdjqwpodwqpodqwjdqwkj qdkjqwkdjqwlkdjqlkdjaslkj   qieoqieowqdjwkjwkj kdwqjqwlk;lqwkd;lkd;laskd;laks;dlkaskld;lakdpoiwdpowqkd;l qwioeqwijdkqwjdlkndlksanlcsmcsa qwkkjeqwjdlkqwjdlksadmasldjl;qkd;asljdlqwkhdlwqk", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abc", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcqdwqdqdqsdqwdwqdsdsaddz", MyTweetType = TweetType.Mine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abc", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcscascqwdwwrewr", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abc", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abc", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="abcqweqwewqeqweqdsdadqwqw", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine},
            new TweetData{ Text="xkwjdwqjdpo", MyTweetType = TweetType.NotMine}
        };
    }

    public List<TweetData> MyTweets { get; }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class TweetData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public TweetType MyTweetType { get; set; }
}

public enum TweetType { Mine, NotMine }
```

Please note that all the UI converters are for horizontal alignment and colors etc and doesn't mess with height or vertical alignments as you can already see in xaml above. I have prepared a sample app for this so you can test it yourself:

https://github.com/touseefbsb/ChatMarginBug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **MinHeight** of the ListViewItem to remove extra space left on bottom of textblock:

```
<Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">​
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />​
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />​
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />​
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,2,12,2" />​
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"></Setter>​
                    </Style>​
</Setter.Value>
```